# How to set the name attribute of a toggled input field on change event

Tags: javascript, events

I am trying to change the attribute `name=""` value of an input field that is toggled once a check box is set and a toggled input is shown and filled out.

User checks a check box, once the check box is checked an input field shows where the title once was. I got this part covered.

Once the input field shows, I want to change the name attribute in that input field with the value the user inputs all before submission of form.

Here is the code I have tried...

```js
document.getElementById('custom-check-box').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    document.getElementById('custom-span').innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="customInputName" name="customInputName" placeholder="Name the custom attribute">';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('custom-span').innerHTML = 'Custom: ';
  }
});
// this bit of code is not working as intended. I want to get the input 
// value after the user changes or focus out of the input and then have that
// value input into the name attribute for the same input.  
document.getElementById('customInputName').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.onChange) {
    let value = document.getElementById('customInputName').value;
    this.setAttribute("name", value);
  }
});
```

```html
<div title="'.$title.'" class="input-info">
  <span id="custom-span">Custom:</span> Yes: <input id="custom-check-box" type="checkbox" class="input-check" name="custom" value="yes">
</div>
```

Error:  `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

I think it is because the input is not set yet in the DOM. Should I set the input in HTML, hide it and then change the name attribute and then show it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am a bit of a beginner with JavaScript.

Thank you in advance!

***SEE ACCEPTED ANSWER FOR UPDATE ON WORKING CODE.*** -> Second snippit was  added an edit to @CertainPerformance code that works better for my use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create the `<input>` *outside* of any of the handlers, and give it the listener which assigns its value to its name. When the checkbox is checked, append the input to the container, otherwise clear the container:

```js
const input = document.createElement('input');
input.name = 'customInputName';
input.placeholder = 'Name the custom attribute';
const customSpan = document.getElementById('custom-span');
document.getElementById('custom-check-box').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    customSpan.textContent = '';
    customSpan.appendChild(input);
  } else {
    customSpan.textContent = 'Custom: ';
  }
});
input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  input.name = input.value;
});
```

```html
<div title="'.$title.'" class="input-info">
  <span id="custom-span">Custom:</span> Yes: <input id="custom-check-box" type="checkbox" class="input-check" name="custom" value="yes">
</div>
```

Comment: Bravo, this works well in my code! it seems so dang easy once I see how you constructed the logic. I have been banging my head with this one for quite some time. Thank you for your time I appreciate it!

Comment: wanted to let you know that I was actually looking to set the name value of the checkbox that has a value of `yes`. Using your example I was able to create a const for that element  and then set the value of the checkbox in the function. I updated my question and placed the working code in a snippit. Thanks again for the assistance!